# Given $\sin(x+y) = z$, and $x$ and $z$ are known, how would I find $y$?

Tags: trigonometry

Given that I have the equation $\sin(x+y)=z$, and $x$ and $z$ are known, how do I find $y$?

For example, if I had $\sin(5+y)=-0.536572981$, what would $y$ be?

In this case, $y=7$.

Comment: The solution for $y$ is not going to be unique.  If you plug $y = 13.28319$ into your equation, it's satisfied as well.  I'll leave it to you to figure out why this is.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert This is because sine has multiple places where values are equal. For example, to get the same value out of $\sin(x)$, simply add $2\pi$ to $x$.

Comment: Right — or any positive or negative multiple of $2\pi$.  So you will, in general, be unable to solve for a unique value of $y$;  there'll be an infinite number of possible values for $y$, all spaced at intervals of $2 \pi$.  Note that the answer that your calculator returns (in the comments to one of the answers) is equal to $7 - 4 \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. Using basic algebra, we have that $\boxed{y = \arcsin(z) - x}.$

Comment: $\arcsin()$ can also be notated as $\sin^-1()$, right?

Comment: Technically, with superscript: $\sin^{-1}()$

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Well, $\arcsin()$ is not on a TI-82, so I can't calculate it easily, and the answer above does not apply to the TI-82's $\sin^-1()$.

Comment: Yeah, it can be written that way, with the $-1$ as a superscript. @SpecialBomb

Comment: This did not solve my problem, as $\arcsin(z)-x$ did not return $y$, unless I'm doing something wrong. In the case I had in my question, the answer that returned was not $7$, but $-5.56637068902$.

Comment: Don't worry about the numbers. Look at your equation. We have $x + y = \arcsin(z).$ Do you understand the meaning of the arcsin function?

Comment: Oh, that was stupid. Sorry, didn't realize that I could use algebra to solve this, as you stated in your answer. And, no, I do not understand the meaning of the $\arcsin$ function.

Comment: That's okay. Just realize that $\arcsin$ is the inverse $\sin$ function. You are "undoing" the $\sin$ function.